# Communication from PySerial to Arduino: corrupted data

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, data-transfer

I need to send orders from a python code (computer) to an Arduino using PySerial via USB. The orders are strings of coma separated values, ended with a termination line character, i.e. `"199,8,0,1,12345,0,0\n"`. The maximum size for an order is 32 bytes.

Here is the code used to send 10 times the same order from python to an Arduino (for debugging purpose).

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodemFA141', 57600)
for i in range(10):
    ser.write("199,8,0,1,12345,0,0\n")
```

On the Arduino side, the order is received, processed, and reformulated using this code:

```
char c = 0;
int it = 0;
bool newData = false;
String lastMessage;
String orderNumber, slaveNumber, singleOrReturn, order, orderComplement, valueI, valueII;

void saveSubStr(String subStr, int iterator){  
  switch (iterator) {
    case 1: orderNumber = subStr; break;
    case 2: slaveNumber = subStr; break;
    case 3: singleOrReturn = subStr; break;
    case 4: order = subStr; break;
    case 5: orderComplement = subStr; break;
    case 6: valueI = subStr; break;
    case 7: valueII = subStr; break;
    default: break; // it might be that some bugs leads the code here
  }
}

void formulateLastMessage(){
  lastMessage = orderNumber+","+slaveNumber+","+singleOrReturn+","+order+","+orderComplement+","+valueI+","+valueII+"\n";
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  it = 0;
  while (Serial.available()){
    c = Serial.read();
    if (c!= '\n'){
      if (c != ','){
        subStr += c;
      }
      else {
        it ++;
        saveSubStr(subStr, it);
        subStr = ""
      }
    }
    else {
      it ++;
      saveSubStr(subStr, it);
      subStr = "";
      newData = true;
      it = 0;
    }
  }
  if (newData) {
    formulateLastMessage();
  }
newData = false;  
}
```

If I send the same order from python 10 time for instance, here are the values I get for the global variable `lastMessage` in the Arduino:

```
199,8,0,1,12345,0,0
199,8,0,1,12345,0,0
199,8,0,1,12345,0,0
0,1,12345,0,0,0,0
199,8,0,1,12345,0,0
199199,8,0,1,12345,0,0
12345,0,0,1,12345,0,0
199,8,0,1,12345,0,0
199,8,0,1,12345,0,0
```

I don't understand why most of the time I receive the data correctly, but sometime the string order is broken. Does anyone has an idea what could cause this problem?

Comment: i edit your python code. Serial got delay for clear answer and clear buffer every sending before.

Comment: @dsgdfg This doesn't solve the issue. I forgot to mention that the problem happen also when I send the orders manually, for instance, a single order every minutes. So it seems that it isn't a timing related problem (at least at the sender).

Comment: `while (Serial.available())` equal to `if (Serial.available() > 0)` ?  why run loop inside loop ? And `clock` (mean time) is everything on serial communication !

Comment: Check your arduino code. `else {
      it ++;
      saveSubStr(subStr, it);
      subStr = "";
      newData = true;
      it = 0;
    }` how will be sure `it` value is correct ? `else {
      saveSubStr(subStr, it+1);
      subStr = "";
      newData = true;
      it = 0;
    }`

Comment: and use global variables. Which condition is on write  ? your code not clear friend.

Comment: @dsgdfg You are right about the redundancy of the loops. Actually in the full program, there are many other operations that are executed in the `loop()` function. I don't understand what you mean with the other comments.

Comment: @dsgdfg I edited the Arduino code for a better clarity.